# What Web Services Language to use with Spring MVC?

Tags: spring, web-services

I have zero knowledge about web-services. However i want to use(Call methods like search etc.) an existing webservice provided by some another system.

Which Web-Service language will be more suitable when my entire project is using spring MVC framework. Is it WSDL , UDDI , SOAP or something else ?

Or does the selection of the language depends on webservice i want to consume ? For e.g.

> UDDI is built into the Microsoft .NET platform

So does that restrict it to Microsoft .NET platform ?

P.S. : I know this sounds like an Open Ended Question, but some some advice will be appreciable

Comment: I'd use [Apache CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/), it integrates nicely with Spring and supports most web service protocols

Comment: also, I'd go with SOAP / WSDL (WSDL is an interface definition for one or more SOAP endpoints)

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to consume or create SOAP webservices I suggest SpringWS which integrates nicely with Spring MVC. You can use Spring webserviceTemplate to consume SOAP services.
http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/reference/html/tutorial.html

IF you are planning to consume REST Spring has restTemplate and Spring MVC provides built-in support for REST based services.

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch18s02.html

Using REST or SOAP will not tie to any specific platform either .NET or Java. Webservices are created to provide communication between different system irrespective of platform or language. 
I suggest while building SOAP based service use Contract first approach i.e start from creating WSDL document and then create client and server components this way it will be compatible with different platforms and languages.